# showing month and year in a mat-picker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to display a calendar with month and year using angular-material
looking through the documentation i saw this but i need the name of the month

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ggalrrqvxdg?file=app%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

i used this code and it shows the name of the month but still show me the day how could i hide that day?

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

Comment: Your stackblitz seems to be working the way you mention you want it to.

Comment: no i shows the number of the month and i need the name of the month

Comment: So just to confirm, you want to see the selected month and year as **June/2019** for eg. Is that right?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yeah thats what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the displayed value in the input use this:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MMM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

The `display: { dateInput: 'MMM/YYYY', ...`  needed an extra `M` to show the name instead of the value.

If you want to full month name (e.g: June instead of Jun), you can have `MMMM/YYYY`.

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to mark this question as resolved if you're good to go :)

Comment: Bro, how can i make to show full name of the month because i got jun./2019 or dic./2019.

Comment: 4 `M`s should do the trick. For future reference you can check this: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options There might be some slight differences but I believe the format is the same as the `DatePipe` in most (if not all) cases

Comment: Little update: it's using the moment.js format, so there are a few differences but at least it's all documented: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Im using configuration to display texts in spanish, and it doesnt show me the first lettter of the month uppercase how could i do that?